# Why are ".exe" much bigger than ".out" when they are compiled from the same c/c++ source code?

Tags: c++, g++

Consider the following c/c++ code:

```
int main () {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = a + b;
}
```

When I compile this using g++ *(MinGW-W64 project)* on Windows, the .exe file ends up being **53KB**

But when I compile it with g++ on Ubuntu, the .out file ends up being only **8KB**

Why is the size difference between the two output files so big?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An executable does not only contain the compiled code, but also additional information, which information will vary between the different executable formats.

With optimizations on your shown code would be completely optimized away, and even with no optimizations, the given code would only result in few bytes of machine-code. So for your program, the ~53KB and ~8KB are the size of the meta-information of the executable.